# Powershell excel header sorting by alphabet

Tags: excel, powershell

I have the following code to get the headers in an excel

$inputTable = Import-Excel -Path $inputFile

$sourceTable = $inputTable | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | %{"$($_.Name)"}

However it is sorting by alphabet. I want the headers in the same sequence  as in the excel. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$inputTable | get-Member -force | where Name -eq "psextended" | %{
$_.Definition.replace('psextended', '').replace('{', '').replace('}', '').Trim() -split ',' | %{$_.trim()}  

}
```

Comment: Another question how come $result = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourceTable -DifferenceObject $targetTable  is giving no result even if the source table and target table have same values but in different order. Any fix for that? The order has to match